# Base64 string to image and vice versa

Tags: java, base64

I have a base64 string stored as a blob in database which I can read and can display in browser easily. Now I want to add watermark on that base64 string and replace in database. For that I use following methods.

```
public static BufferedImage addWaterMark(BufferedImage bufferedImage, String waterMark) {
    try {
        // create graphics object and add original image to it
        Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        graphics.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);

        // set font for the watermark text
        graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
        //unicode characters for (c) is \u00a9

        // add the watermark text
        graphics.drawString(waterMark, 0, 10);
        graphics.dispose();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return bufferedImage;
}
public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type) {
    String imageString = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
        byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();

        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        imageString = encoder.encode(imageBytes);

        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageString;
}
public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) {

    BufferedImage image = null;
    byte[] imageByte;
    try {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

I got following string from database

```
String base64String = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZAAAABkCAYAAACoy2Z3AAAXzElEQVR4Xu2db4xcV3nGn/fMrmM7MbihraiaBjtZpylex7NGpR8IxBFFUVtaO1A+kA+Ng6qEUlVJUCMh2gpHiBZQK5wPIBW1ZFOphaIAmyJQFSLFEala+sE7xrMxxeN4S6pGrSrixBvb2Zk5b/Wee+/M3ZnZnTuzOzt3Z56RQtjMueee+3vv3Oee8/45An5IgARIgARIoA8C0scxPIQESIAESIAEQAHhTUACJEACJNAXAQpIX9h4EAmQAAmQAAWE9wAJkAAJkEBfBCggfWHjQSRAAiRAAhQQ3gMkQAIkQAJ9EaCA9IWNB5EACZAACVBAeA+QAAmQAAn0RYAC0hc2HkQCJEACJLBlBeSmWw++38NdWvzR/HM0IwmQAAmQwOYT2LICMjV9SAEFIMcr5VOPbj46npEESIAExpvAlhSQqekZU47wEbFL0EVVva9SLp0cb3Py6kmABEhg8whsWQGJhANQ1csAdtrfde+frlX10z/58ennNw8hz0QCJEAC40lgSwqImWpq+tBxCB4S4M2qehVRWa/tJim1Jb1+cbF0cTxNyqsmARIggc0hsGUFxPDsubW4Z2JSTgjkiGq0qmUzEVXMVcqn7t4chDwLCZAACYwngS0tIInJpqaLhwF5RkQKqvoGgGvqqg9cWCh9eTzNyqsmARIggcETGAkBiZa0iodF3LORX8T+1/vaEt7CpazB30Q8AwmQwHgSGBkBMfPdPH3ohEAfNA0REVHFo5XyqePjaVpeNQmQAAkMlsBICciePcXdE9fJ/4rIpOWIKHCxdkn3chYy2JuIvZMACYwngZESEDPhvgPFY4B7PIrMwnbv9bEXXyg9NJ7mzedV37B3+rZt2+WGF8+e+W4+R8hRkQAJZCEwcgIS+UNmFkXkbXFklorqoXMLpVIWIGwzWAIh/Br+zwBxEFwUyBy8f4z2GSx39k4CgyAwkgJisxBVedx8IRbZGx5UXu/kQ2oQt1C2PuNIua8CeGuoHQDUARTs6CT0ulbzDy/+qLSYrUe2IgESGDaBkRSQeBayJCLXquoVADsoIsO51W685eDthQn5TMHJe1LVA+ISNBYx598AnIpgu6q+5uu1D3Npazi24llJoFcCIysgsUO9ZEtZUF1S4DqKSK+3x/raT+0/9BBEv9CcZViOjny2tuRPTO7CUVU5JiJ32Peq+iqAN9v/rZTn3frOzKNJgAQ2g8DICojBs0z1yQmZg8hBqP+pQq63t2APf/f5M6W5zQA8juewWcdEwX2xUMBtQRwCBP1erYb7W5eoQv4O5ITZKKkmUCnPj/R9OY73BK95NAmM/A/VZiKT18nJ+AG1LMA2r3hNPZdKBnFL33ygeFRUvpXMOqw0mULft1al5Hi2+Eo4Bjh9rjxfHMTY2CcJkMDGEhh5AQkzkRYRAWSbZapXyqXgxOVnYwhM7S/+vYjc06i1r/hcZWH+E916T6oI2AxERO87d6Y02+0Yfk8CJDB8AmMhIAnmfdMzJQUONt6O4fmw2oB70Jastk26f4Dgl4KjXLUK1XdmjXq7ebr4vBP3LqtjVlvStzLxcwOMwi5IYBMIjJWApDPV4/X2k5Xy/J2bwHlkT7Fi+SlUQtZv15b097KKQPBTTboLBqhe08+9eLb7jGVkYfLCSGCLERgrATHbWCKbCD6lqlUreVKt+r3MPej/rp3aX7wqIteEZSut/2Fl4Ydf6qU3q1/mBA+aoNdqSlv0Ao9tSWDIBMZOQNJvvN57q9z7+IsvlD4yZDtsydPv218swrn5eDb37Up5/nd6vZCp6ZllE3L1WqsszE/2ejzbkwAJDI/A2AlImIUcmJlLbULFUid93n9JnocJiHPo2Z+UXv4C8FylPH+4z6HwMBIggSEQGEsBSYeaGnMRLFYv6UzWdfsh2CmXpzQhhuKIDc7Xa7/Vawb5yugrPHHuzPyxXF4oB0UCJNCRwFgKSJiF7J+5Ik6sfMYVEdkB1VJ1Se+kiGT/pUztL9YhEmWN91FvzITcwX0rFN5X4d4t2dGzJQnkgsDYCkhYPtnlFsXKZ6j+VIHrbSYCr3dnDT/NhQWHOIhEhJMs/15FpBnQEC6CAjJEW/LUJNAPgbEVEINlTmB17qSJCIsu9n77pBM0ExHRHrL80wKiwvIyvVuAR5DAcAmMtYB0EJFQ0K+Xh+BwzTf8s3cSEUC9KN7RbSa378DMLCD3ht0jVe9cq9zJ8K+UIyABEmglMPYCYkA6FV20h2BtCW+hT6T7jyYRkSjLX31js6gue7BMTc+ctGq8FsXFAordObMFCeSNAAUktsjKh2C8ERXATPWMd2zwKV0rL1tgQlafyL4Dh0L+ofd68fzC/M9kPBWbkQAJ5IQABSRliPRDUFUtwW2bKp27We/VlqKVa27ktbJqLwsoZmXMdiSQJwIUkBZrpB3r0do8UKvXP7x49odfy5Ph8jqWTiLSyac0NV18WsS9Tz2u1l73v8ClwrxalOMigdUJUEA6sLE91QH3uKpeBbA9WtfHe+nkzfZT6jgTSTnWV5aT0a+eX5i/J1vPbEUCJJAnAhSQVaxhEUKqsAih4BSO9vNm+fesN2+LY10t3z9hqOr2xAUtIaoz3aK1sp6T7UiABDaXAAVkFd4r/SH+DYFcYzVPAMxWL/mHueTS/UZt8ykB24yh9+qdE+fVXz5fLl3bvSe2IAESyCMBCsgaVomL/c1ZqKk1S8qeqNcXvK890mvtpzzeAIMeU3o5y0MvO2Cn1T2xSsge+v0LC6ffM+gx5LV/24jLV+uv/deF8g/zOkaOiwTWIkAByXB/JHtWxCISkg2zJstl6H4smjSTBgFvC1ohUhoq0IfPlUuPjQWEsB9N8TDEHYH6e0TczwNaO3eGZezHxf6jdp0UkIwWDWGncLNQNfEIa/q91n7KeKqRbWbl38XhC/H+IeE6zS+iqidrNb1vFDf2shlY4Voccc4d9qp3W9mcaNffhpnPVsrzbx9Zo/PCRpoABaQH81r00ERBzvaSLNdD92PR9Ka3F+edk2LkUA/Lgm8AuCYSEhyvlE89utVB2H1SKOAOEXcU0KPJ9STXnPytXpcrC/PXbPXr5fjHlwAFpEfbdywgCLyq9do99ImsDTPZQMoepF71shPZGYvIawDeFD1gddFDHz5/pjTXo2mG2vyGvdO3bd9R+KA4Z7syFhXhWsIMK/2JS9fDwz/jl/AhBmMM1Ww8+ToJUED6ANguIs5KwVva4UUoSoCcrKv/7+rl2g/oIG0Cvmn/zDNO8F77L7b/+WQBuyEyC5GDsZAE/9JWWdZKlqdspiGCo8nSXFo0LIkSqhdU9KCteSrgRet/1Ove8X3cpjyEBAZOgALSJ+KW2lm2/KIh0UFscyTrNLyBam1Jr+dbZuQ8FnHPBtx1/5fnXig9kqAPW+M6HA97swRquAro9iAkXp+8ern66TwJcXwt93qvHxCRN4WZRphvNHw6LynkmwI/B8gnANwV3xE1qP4q8176/NHxsNwRoICswyQrCgim+km/iapirlI+dfc6TjMSh05Nz1RFZMJqjFXK7ev+QZB3yYmovLuJiH8DlnsDCek35h+pLfnHhiXGUcVmHFGVj0NwY/jhpJenVKse8iWnftYEIl6uOy0iN8bX8++1Jdw1rPGPxE3Ei8gdAQrIBpgkOE0nURR1RUAPA/oeESeJg7iu+sCFhdKXN+BUW7KLUF9MZD5+5q6593kIc4UcT8q8N1/sbflHLwpkrlr1j25WxFZU9NFZRQJbpopnlpEZVHFJRL+pqrPpMjd2vRD5PkSus3Ze9a/Pl+c/uiWNx0GTwBoEKCADuD3SyzXRbES9AB8fp3yHNNZ0+K5Itsq7Yb90la9DZDJ+g18C5LqUf2FW1T8xiPpkcUHNe9XrRxpLVKnZhkKfUuhsJ0f/3ltue3fhmsKzAil4tY216O8YwE+MXeaEAAVkQIaw5EOBPph+g4ZqSaEPD+KhN6DL2JBub54ufseJ+03zElSrureX2YMVtlQNM5K3pYUkms1EOSQ2Azi/UHpiPYNdEUUlKEaZPs2fh6q+BMhXajU/u9r499x64NjEROFvRZxT1aqovpP+jvVYhcfmnQAFZEAWavWPqGojVHWUE+c64ZyanvEWYOC9/7/zC6Wf6wd5u5CESskOwLYk/Lfuda5W1W/85Menn89yjmipCXcAcgwixU5RVIA+0bpE1anvkCM0IRcix7+3Apxfq6s/Vb1S/16eAgCycGEbEshKgAKSlVSf7aamDx23yrPR27M99EK8TiPCaLnqH8v6wOtzCEM9bGr/bR+DFL4YDWL9+56nfSTJhanqZQh2WmGUeNKw6vJWXFHgDoEeVYVVBY7qCqSiqKB6GqInqpcwl9XpPbV/5oolmJoI2T/OOo5mSKqiH9hKeS033Xrw/RBRNyFLnW4eX9Pg22n9frX/DuhuBP9g/BFf8jXUlq/WXqK4DvXnue6TU0DWjbB7B/Hb6WyqKGO8z0j0VB3lelBT08XXRNwur/4/zpdLt3anla1FtKeIHFfIUQv/jWcPIZLWekhmJVr3fwfBFUjh19JZ4c028fniKKp6zZ/oZYktGa0JCMT2jmkufZl2RH+G/I8TlTOnHs52dZvTypbttu2YmHbO7bPkRxEtArInftlpS4JMj8ourTVJsu04E9OWS0lHrwU8gpA7JdA5KJ7jkt/m2H6jzkIB2SiSGfppjzDS6J3ZMrPr+m/Vmn9klGYjNvsQN/HFOJDgzkH4fqKlQndMRD+fONzDCpJiWZxsi/PBoxS+lqxwm2koZE7Uz23EgysSNVgU2WFV2CZZkyZeAuwI5SO9vrBc9Q+02jhcwy45uPobPNDPd5Uz88/ZPefrCCXzxeFnxbkiVG3priiQ3bHGRVnzkfqFGVSbwKbu79W+73ZcqwCpwpY2XTpjP4m0U/i5ypnSUxl+VmwyRAIUkCHAD1FakKebEUaWOIftyfLLZoapDvLyp6aLdXMoe/WvnC+Xrh/kuazvvfuL9xdE/sRyL1Z9yEEvQ/X55WX99CDFujWvBapLCoSln05v7gmb1d7su80K1jouOTY6R7JY17RGW7mVVWYX3cbYNoYg0LiYtrsgVB842Gm8YSkylPuPAySgF73im8uvVx/Ly1KX2dXtwLtsjKst8W3Efb7WC0PW/nvto5f2tUt62pZ3KSBZrTGAdol/JL380igy6PXJrewf2Wjfx1r4w496p/y5c/iD9CMyjtJKHxp8JVZSJHwsKs77f7p6pf6NQT2ggvMf7kSyzKZAXYBCMqiWSK/oEd86U4r8Z319lxaP1n69qo3leSu9I+IX4VHaiJlYlp9KkjsFdYed5U7F5WwaIuX9JYjsimzofaVcajDL0n/WNlHItoQKCFA5HGvs7jBLi+TWBK/pv4lt0clua51zrZeGTsd1eyHIcn299tFbe108d2Z+LwUkiyUG2CbcwJB/DRV+owzskO+QysCeg/jZrTadH5Tvo9UUURkU/xmo7Gz8SFNZ4d5hj0COCeRI4+Gkuhw/HLbZwk3sSJ9T9XP11/FUVsd51tsisbH5SIY1+xDgtAoWoVIC/MlaDYv9+Hra+B+YCZut2dtroWDP4M6O926sRPU6FXmHevy6c/LulK1s/5jSiwvzM536SJb/kjHYv6OZQavjHk1REOxJfD1pgW32nzwWV3pwkheSXsWg27W3ft/bg7xz77320Ut7r3oRkCfOl089RAHp1boDap8OU23OSKISjf2GqQ5oqF27tWsB3OOD8n0E5+/Oifuc4PfFxDYpDe/1rDj9/LkzpdnWQaZ8JRaymxRvjJvFZQ4bJeaxIWLSGs0UlggKmEqPzYk90Dfms9ZDXFSLCrd7lTNZBYW27zq9fa8+0kb8wsZcTB+9JA/B9H4zq4lCWymajOfruPQGvGqz2VW7ECkmdd6ynKaXh/lq/fXaRy/tVfW5Snk+zNYoIFksuoltwsNX5cuJfyR+Q2oJU9VFW3ao1evlq68sP/nyy2f/cxOH2PVUzbpX9auV8ukdXQ9INTBxmNhe+JWJQiGK2JLmm2P4U6JlhvQNr+r/RwSf6CQcnc4dlk8m3EMO+rE2zrAS880II8vZsQihag1P2Rt7iKibtKTG9Buula8J/ue2N9u2t9UukUm9sGpvu/IhHm971leXqQ2v2o5vj0Voj0/o66QdDloxDgnzxY5d9/IAbO1AVe33sxjuK0hJGn4bfzLddhBBIBvFaVj9UECGRb7LeaN8hebSS+OtSuEhcEl0UZzF8GheNmLa+8sHPuQmCl8PDxmRfwbwWbvUtXIH1NeunZgs3K5wv2G7vsbljBvvN831/5XQFHIFqv+oHk/assVaTsDE6deKPV5e+lMF7hKx/IYwcHuULAOyrTmWlG9ihQh0Xu6IxW7z7q71qMV6RznMc8djX/lCoc+lLyktCiq+JIqL9s9m+XvWizfPx1NA8mwdAFEOiTsm0E+2vC03Rt7IeVC9b1hvSVEIq/uUqh7rmh+QYp7lzTFLm9ZZSa9mzbTs0cG5vdp5Vh3zGpFJvY55RfsOD/H0m3XnvmXFG3bSxhzqqtEbeadPt3useS/4DwJuV6eNtaK3/Wjpxx7wTnypWsXJVr9MFPoefWpLKG20f2pdzHkwl7C20j2QzjOA5Rk0Cg1G4Y/24K57/3StOtgQ1TSzG285ePu2SfegOPxua/2opN1qD9MswpClzUaIRy+OURtT83mdpLKvXD5qinr8IDZfh8YhraInk9nSi2dL39lK9+BaY40qF8uDIjgcb44SmsfiXIXgu/ByEuJLFIPRsDpnIFvYjhYGDIFFQlgmdqNMSvjNblL5jKnpYkgnXitCZasISPqNXQSLqhKti9drPxLnboeTG+D1t8U5q8G16ke9Xo2y0tuXt9LJeh3yL1IzArH8iZWOWfG222Ujr2KtJTtLIrQBhjd4sV3Oun/S/a225JfuxSoPSwHThYmJd67YXKsZjHBJga8ke6R0HwFbbDUCFJCtZrGW8cZO3RMWphpHPTWy2wF/X1bHcj8YkvpPjRlAyPZ2jZyF0GdwJ3ROXvPe/4tz+JtBjrGf6+p2TLSsaA5zd1iB3QK1KJuQINft2PRsSaF1aDMnZGVMS+dnfmv+QS8zp25jyzrbS/rx3oINor9WjsuXRfBXW82u3fjw+3YCFJARuSvS2e0KvSKKHVFZChwflIM9qf+U3mhprYS3gLpl574Rwd+4jGgnQsSJZy6KGItFJm5ktabett4Hf68P+26cW/tL6nitdVz7NegT8HqCzulutEfnewrI6NgS6fIZHnrZhbIQg6mzZb6PyQn5Y4gcsQWdKNwy9oJE9ZSi0MhQLE9KFv1Sr6K0Eclro2Ky5kwmTNJ2RztaJm/0useqBbdc657mviidixn2y6ZXQYpnu29YpF0Ic+6hcnG/Y+Rx+SNAAcmfTdY9on0HZmabe4un6mxFES9zAn9RRUrJmrdXLHR6sFuIa93jF21AFiabJKOFUuiI3rIbpVfq/pOVF0p/se7Bs4NcEFg5k2ofUrdIrFxcBAcxcAIUkIEjHs4J0tvIRlMD8SJaSOprZy3LsCK8NeXPaNbs8j8Q4KNcthiOnXlWEhgmAQrIMOkP+NytdbbSp2tbsoiT49IlHtaKngJQFdH76SgdsBHZPQnkmAAFJMfG2aihBSERdxS2YZDG1UVV39zNkduoLZTU+on9GRu1f8ZGXR/7IQESGA4BCshwuOfurEnGL0s85M40HBAJ5JYABSS3puHASIAESCDfBCgg+bYPR0cCJEACuSVAAcmtaTgwEiABEsg3AQpIvu3D0ZEACZBAbglQQHJrGg6MBEiABPJNgAKSb/twdCRAAiSQWwIUkNyahgMjARIggXwToIDk2z4cHQmQAAnklgAFJLem4cBIgARIIN8EKCD5tg9HRwIkQAK5JUABya1pODASIAESyDcBCki+7cPRkQAJkEBuCVBAcmsaDowESIAE8k2AApJv+3B0JEACJJBbAhSQ3JqGAyMBEiCBfBOggOTbPhwdCZAACeSWAAUkt6bhwEiABEgg3wQoIPm2D0dHAiRAArklQAHJrWk4MBIgARLINwEKSL7tw9GRAAmQQG4JUEByaxoOjARIgATyTYACkm/7cHQkQAIkkFsCFJDcmoYDIwESIIF8E/h/1iN2ChJ6swYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
```

My issue is when I try to write new buffered Image to some location i can see that proper watermarked image in picture viewer. but when I convert that image file back to base64 I got a string.

```
String imageDataBytes = base64String.substring(base64String.indexOf(",")+1);
        File outputfile = new File("d://abc.png");
        ImageIO.write(addWaterMark(decodeToImage(imageDataBytes), "wateermark"), "png", outputfile);
```

So what is proper way to convert base64 string to image and back to base64 string? Any help or guideance are accepted.

When I tried String to buffered image and again image to String without any watermark updation I should get same result as orignal string but I am not getting it. output of bellow code are different for both line why?

```
String imageDataBytes = base64String.substring(base64String.indexOf(",")+1);
        System.out.println(imageDataBytes);
        System.out.println(encodeToString(decodeToImage(imageDataBytes),"png");
```

Comment: When you Base64 encode an image (bytes) you get a String.  So you are correct, when you convert an image file back to base64 you will get a string..

Comment: check my edit please